# Why is my crap4j.xml missing after running phpunit?

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, xdebug

Here is my config. Jenkins fails the build because it can't see the file. My local Ubuntu 14.04 VM isn't creating it and the jenkins AWS 14.04 instance is having the jenkins build fail. Xdebug and tokenizer are enabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "../app/bootstrap.php.cache" >

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="../build/coverage"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="../build/logs/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="coverage-crap4j" target="../build/logs/crap4j.xml"/>
    <log type="junit" target="../build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>

<!--
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
</php>
-->

<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory>../src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>

<groups>
    <exclude>
        <group>Acceptance</group>
    </exclude>
</groups>

<listeners>
    <listener class="\Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\TestListener"></listener>
</listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: put the log, is possible?

Answer (score 2):

What's your PHPUnit version?

The `--coverage-crap4j` option was introduced in PHPUnit 4.0.0.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/ChangeLog-for-PHPUnit-4.0#phpunit-400